# Mark all line if checkbox is true

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I will give an example:

I have checkboxes in `B3:G3`.
This is a checklist, I want to change the background color to green for `A3:H3` if `B3:G3` boxes are checked.

Can someone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Go to the menu: Format -> Conditional formatting.

1. Specify the range to be applied the rule on the *"Apply to range"* field, in your case `A3:H3`
2. On *format rule* select `Custom formula is`
3. Write the formula: `=AND($B3=TRUE, $C3=TRUE, $D3=TRUE, $E3=TRUE, $F3=TRUE, $G3=TRUE)`
4. Select the formatting style: the color background.

Answer (score 0):

- all you need to do is to offset the range you are applying to:

  ```
  =B3=TRUE
  ```

  [image: 0]